# xcode - alert that shows crash reason

Tags: objective-c, xcode, crash

Is there a way to build an alert box that shows what the crash reason is? Specifically, what line of code is causing the crash?

My boss is asking for this, and I haven't found a way to make this possible. I'm going through the analytics tab on the device and finding the crash, but he wants something that populates on the device (it's an internal app) giving the reason for the crash.

Is this possible?

Comment: when the app is crashed, it quits to home screen, there is no way you can show a popup before or after crash!

Comment: IOS apps have build in Testflight feature. You will be able to retrieve crash reports in Xcode->Window->Organizer->Crashes already. Or alternatively you can add Fabric's Crashlytics in app and see crash reports on web.

Comment: Ok ... so what i'm seeing is that what my boss is asking for is impossible ... i've gotten it to be able to open an alert that says "App has crashed" and send info ... but that's essentially what i'm getting already. 

Thanks for giving me ammo for when i speak to my boss!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show an alert when app crashes you can't do that but you can read the crash log when you open the app again after a crash.

You could create a method with following logic, it basically reads back trace for last crash when you open the app again after a crash.

```
aslmsg q, m;
    int i;
    const char *key, *val;
    float how_old = fTime ;
    q = asl_new(ASL_TYPE_QUERY);
    asl_set_query(q, ASL_KEY_LEVEL, strLoggerLevel ,ASL_QUERY_OP_LESS_EQUAL);
    asl_set_query(q, ASL_KEY_FACILITY, [@"YourBundleIdOfAPP" UTF8String] ,ASL_QUERY_OP_EQUAL);

    asl_set_query(q, ASL_KEY_TIME, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - how_old] UTF8String], ASL_QUERY_OP_GREATER_EQUAL);
    int goInside=0;
    aslresponse r = asl_search(NULL, q);
    while (NULL != (m = aslresponse_next(r)))
    {
        NSString *cValueToWrite;
        NSMutableDictionary *tmpDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        for (i = 0; (NULL != (key = asl_key(m, i))); i++)
        {
            //get the only required fields
            if(i==12 || i==10 || i==11 || i==8 || i==9 ||i==3)
            {

                NSString *keyString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)key];
                val = asl_get(m, key);

                NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:val];
                [tmpDict setObject:string forKey:keyString];
            }
        }

cValueToWrite=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"\n--------------[Debug]----------------\nDateTime: %@\nApplication: %@\nInfo: %@",[tmpDict valueForKey:@"CFLog Local Time"],[tmpDict valueForKey:@"Sender"],[tmpDict valueForKey:@"Message"]];
}
```

`strLoggerLevel` is the `NSString` which hold the logger type which you want which ranges upto 7